# How does the NPM cache and node_modules folder work hand in hand?

Tags: npm

I am trying to demystify this NPM behavior. I have a custom library which I create for an Angular Project. The library is copied directly to the Node modules directory in my Angular Folder to test any new functionalities that I add on whatever project is using it. However, I notice the older version of the library is being used by the project.

I wonder whether this is due to the NPM Cache.

So my question is, how does the NPM cache and Node_Modules folder work hand in hand?

Answer (score 0):

I can't directly answer as to how the cache relates to `node_modules`, but I *can* say that your `package-lock.json` file is likely the culprit behind your outdated packages.  Try running `npm update`.  If that doesn't work, try deleting your `package-lock.json` file and running `npm install`.

If that also doesn't work, make sure you have the correct version specified for your library in your project's `package.json` file.  `latest` will grab the latest release available, `^1.0.0` will grab the latest minor and patch releases, `~1.0.0` will grab only the latest patch releases, and `1.0.0` will only grab that exact version.